# Groovy Compiler config: Want global CompileStatic but with TypeChecking off

Tags: groovy, typechecking, groovyc

I have search everywhere for this answer, and I thinking it can't be done.

Here is my compiler-config.groovy file:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

withConfig(configuration) {
  ast(CompileStatic)
}
```

What i want to do is add some additional config params to turn off Type Checking. In essence I want my entire groovy project compiled static but I dont want it to do any type checking. Is this possible?

Comment: Quick question - have you tried the configuration you have shown in the question?  It looks like your compiler configuration adds `@CompileStatic` only.

Comment: Uh, yeah. That is the problem. CompileStatic by default applies TypeChecking. I want static compiling, that checks class methods etc and other compiler issues, but I dont want it to do any TypeChecking.

Answer (score 0):

Normally your compiler-config file should looks like this:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.TypeCheckingMode

withConfig(configuration)  {
    ast(CompileStatic, value: TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)
}
```

But in my case (Groovy 2.5.1), groovy ignore the "value" and still use TypeCheckingMode.PASS. I guess it could be a bug.

Workaround what I found is use `@CompileStatic(TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)` or `@CompileDynamic` (this is shortcut for previous one) annotations on the class which should skip TypeChecking.